# Do personal development questions fit anywhere on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd like to ask for advice on becoming more socially intelligent; for example, when encountering another person whose behaviour people describe as difficult or troublesome, I usually don't see what the problem is until someone points it out to me. But I suspect that questions asking "How can I improve *x* personal aspect?" or "How to be more *y*" don't fit comfortably on Stack Exchange; I've not seen any site so far which appears to house such questions. There's [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/), but that seems to concentrate on external issues rather than internal ones.

So my question has three parts:

1. Is there an appropriate SE website for questions about personal development?
2. If not, should I try to propose this website on Area 51?
3. Or, is this topic area too unsuitable for SE?

Comment: I notice that someone has proposed a [self-improvement](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67964/self-improvement) SE on Area 51, but this appears geared towards people who want to help other people (therapists, coaches etc.) not for people who want help themselves.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**: The Productivity Stack Exchange site has been closed for a while now. But the other sites are still an option!

<strike>If you're looking for advice, there is a [social-interaction](/questions/tagged/social-interaction) tag on [Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/) with [questions](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-interaction) like "[How to Improve Inter-personal Skills](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/q/4440/6938)".</strike>

Depending on the setting in question, you might want to consider [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) or [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), especially if you can break your question down into one specific issue at a time that arises commonly in the given setting.

If you're not looking for personalized advice, but are interested in scientific theory and research on social intelligence and its modification, consider [Cognitive Sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/). The [social-psychology](/questions/tagged/social-psychology) and [intelligence](/questions/tagged/intelligence) tags may be of use. For an example question, compare "[Accuracy of social judgements of observers watching business meetings](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/340/4086)".

Comment: I am looking for advice. I don't know if PP is what I want though, it's explicitly work-focused. This leads me to think I should put a proposal on Area 51, but I want to make sure nobody thinks that this is inappropriate for an SE site proposal.

Comment: It's not inappropriate, but it's not very unique. You'll have a hard time getting the site proposal to survive given all the overlap (competition, effectively) in your area of interest. A Mental Fitness beta tried to go this way and failed pretty miserably a month or two ago.

Comment: Do you mean that it's too broad in focus?

Comment: I'm just a little confused by "not very unique", because you seem to be suggesting that the topic encompasses too many areas. I don't see where uniquity comes into it.

Comment: I think Nick is not saying that the idea lacks specificity, but that it is already being submitted fairly often.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE::** The websites mentioned here is closed now. The answer has become irrelevent.

<strike>I think this site https://productivity.stackexchange.com/ would probably be your best bet.</strike>

From there https://productivity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic page :

> What topics can I ask about here?

> Personal Productivity Stack Exchange
> is for people wanting to improve their personal productivity. If you
> have a question about...
> achieving a productivity workflow, using techniques like GTD, Covey, Pomodoro, etc.
> fighting procrastination by getting energetic and motivated
> workflow
> ergonomics
> effective sleep habits and the entire sleep-wake transition
> **learning**, memory and creativity

Comment: Not quite what I'm after, I'm more interested in questions like 'How can I be less aggressive' or 'How can I improve my hand eye coordination' or in my case 'How can I be more socially critical?' Productivity is work related, what I'm looking for is more broadly about self improvement

Comment: This site is closed

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't, but there should be one, if not many.

Personal Productivity, is not what your looking for and besides its closed anyways.

Comment: Self improvement is an all encompassing subject. It deals with helping a person develop, change, and grow.
possibly there is no Stack exchange self improvement equivalent, because it wouldn't flourish, unless there was a large group of people who work on their self improvement.
The question is why wouldn't therapists and social workers seek to create such a site?
Also the questions that may be asked have allot more depth then a tech problem or a math problem, even if they may be more sophisticated. 
Depth requires self work and to be of any value, and can't just be theorized about.