# Which site can I ask questions about personal development?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Can I ask questions regarding "internal" personal development, i.e. about dealing with certain aspects of one's mind, on the Interpersonal Skills SE site? I think it wouldn't quite fit because even if this can affect social relationships, they are not at the heart of the issue.

Do you know some other site where I can discuss such questions (SE or non-SE)?

There is already a similar question here: [Do personal development questions fit anywhere on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234058/do-personal-development-questions-fit-anywhere-on-stack-exchange) but it focuses on becoming more socially intelligent (so it would fit at the Interpersonal Skills site, in my opinion).

Comment: Do you mean like improving your memory?

Comment: Not quite, more like e.g. how to cope with "wrong"/"inappropriate" thoughts like vicious circles

Comment: "Discuss" is [a trigger word](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbsACrtT9h0&t=155s)...

Comment: People shouldn't be asking questions about medical problems, including psychological problems, but it would be reasonable to ask where one can ask other types of personal development questions. I guess Life Hacks could work for those with more immediate, practical solutions, and Parenting, Interpersonal Skills, The Workplace, etc, may help with others in specific areas. But if you post in the wrong forum people are usually quick to tell you where to go!

Comment: I think "intrusive thoughts" is the term you're looking for, maybe that'll help you find the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be off-topic on Interpersonal Skills SE. Interpersonal Skills are the behaviors one uses when interacting with others, while attempting to achieve certain goals.

Things that are only inside your head are at their best intrapersonal (and as such, off-topic), at their worst they require more help than random internet strangers and you'd be better off if you seek the help of a trained professional. There is currently no site taking questions like that.